# Webserver and Cloudfront distribution with the same domain name

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We have a (django) wep application that is running at example.com and we would like to serve some static assets on s3 via cloudfront from this same domain.  So if we had a file with key assets/img.jpg we would be able to access it via example.com/assets/img.jpg.

We have been attempting to use this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html) but have only been able to get it working with a subdomain to access cloudfront so static.example.com/assets/img.jpg

The issue we are running into is the DNS setup for this, there is already a CNAME for example.com (web app) that routes traffic to the server, but we are unable to create a second entry with the same name example.com to the cloudfront distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, go to the configuration for your Cloudfront distribution.

From there, you need to create another "origin" that points to that S3 bucket, and then a "behavior" for the "/assets/*" path to send the traffic to that S3 bucket.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response, that seems doable but running into a problem on the DNS setup creating two CNAME entries for example.com, one to the webserver and one to the cloudfront.

Comment: You don't need 2 cname records, just one A record to the cloudfront distributions url. Both your web app and your s3 bucket should be origins where the default behavior will route traffic to your web server (running in EC2?) and additional behavior you'll create for the  /assets/* path will send traffic to your S3 origin.

Comment: I attempted this but not quite sure how to achieve, I have an A (Alias) record for example.com pointing to cloudfront distribution and a behavior on the distribution for /assets/* pointing to s3 bucket, but how would I create an origin for the app with the same example.com domain, Route 53 rejects this.

Comment: You dont need more than one record, both your web server and your s3 bucket should be origins in your cloudfront distribution, not separate records in route53. I'm confused where your issue is, you're describing the setup I have for 3 seperate sites, 2 of which are rails apps the other a python app, all have their assets stored in S3 buckets. It's important to understand that Cloudfront is a reverse proxy and how that works.

Comment: Ah I see my error, I was confused about what to put in the origin domain for the web app inserting the Public IPv4 DNS entry of my EC2 fixed the issue.  I am to go to example.com view and use the application.  But I am not able to access the s3 files I placed a test.txt file in my bucket, and went to example.com/assets/test.txt and got a 404 (seems to be running through the app as it is checking the url conf there).

Comment: I would check the origin path settings and be sure they match the path in the s3 bucket, you're almost there my dude!